# cap deploy:setup creates the release folder with root as owner

Tags: capistrano

I am using capistrano to deplay my rails application on a Ubuntu server.

I already logged into the server and created a folder /webapps/myapp, but no sub folders from here.

Then I run

```
cap deploy:setup
```

No errors so far, so i run

```
cap deploy:setup
```

Now I get this message

```
You do not have permissions to write to /webapps/myapp/releases
```

I can get around this by logging in to the server and change the owner of releases, I just wonder why it is not created with the user I use for deploying? Is this how it work or am I missing something?

Comment: I am facing this exact issue and have the same question. Why did it create releases folder with root owner instead of the user used to deploy. Haven't found an answer yet.

Answer (score 9):

In your deploy.rb file you should specify the deployment user and if he has sudo privilege.

```
set :user, "william"
set :use_sudo, false
```

Giving sudo privilege isn't recommended, but this option exists.

The directory to which you deploy should be already owned by the deployment user "william"

Comment: If i log into the server and creates a folder /my_app and change the ownership to my deploy user. Then i run the deploy:setup which creates the releases folder. This folder is still owned by root:root.

Comment: Why can't capistrano create the app root folder with that user's ownership? I had to create the app folder and change the ownership manually, before running deploy:setup :(